# How JQuery Ajax works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send data from JQuery Ajax to a Generic Handler that calculates something and returns a result. The Ajax request is made inside a `for` loop at JQuery end. The code looks something like this:

```
function send(Handler, ids) {
    var URL = "http://" + window.location.host + "/Handlers/" + Handler + ".ashx";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var cur = $('.' + ids[i]);
        $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                Data: cur
            }),
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: //my before send code,
            success: //my success code,
            error: //my error code
        });
    }
    alert('Done!');
}
```

I placed 3 breakpoint in Visual Studio 2012 at line:

```
$.ajax({
```

this

```
alert('Done!');
```

And third breakpoint at first line in the Generic Handler.

Now, when I try to execute this code, the Ajax works nicely in async way. But, when it reaches the first breakpoint, stops there and then I resume it, instead of reaching the Generic Handler's breakpoint, it continues the loop and goes back to first breakpoint. Then after it reaches the second breakpoint it then stops at generic handler's break point again and again for each value.

So, does that mean that Ajax first collects all the ajax requests and then after the `for` loop it executes them together?

Comment: No, the requests do start immediately with each call to `$.ajax()`, but don't complete before the loop continues to start the next request or `alert('Done!')`. The handlers (`success`, etc.) are setup to be called when the response has been received, which happens "in their own time" (asynchronously), unbound by the loop or each other.

Comment: If the server code is also under your control, having a web service that returns multiple results (e.g. for an array of ids) is far more efficient that what you are doing. As a side-effect, if you switch to that pattern, you will avoid this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is single threaded and non-blocking. This means that in the first iteration won't wait for the ajax call to be completed, it will go back and start the second iteration, and so on. 
So, no it doesn't executes them all together. It definately starts the ajax calls in the order of the loop but there is no way to tell what will end first. It might make all the ajax calls and then get an answer (doesn't mean it is the answer of the first iteration), or in the middle of a loop it might be getting answers.

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding you correctly, you just answered your own question. Ajax is working asynchronously meaning the for loop starts and fires out ajax requests, and continues the loop (the ajax request **DOES NOT** block)

Therefore it is very likely that the js is performing a loop of code before the request reaches your url (as this has to create a network call)

That said, what are you doing in your beforeSend method? maybe this is making it take enough time that it can perform all iterations of the loop before sending the first request?

To answer your question, no it shouldn't be waiting for the for loop to finish in order to send off the requests, it should be initiating the process as soon as you have made the call